# Shift/Move one button's position to another button's position in android animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I have three buttons in the view. On Clicking first button, it should move to second button's position. And second button should move to third button's position. And third button should hide from the view. As I am newbie to android, I am unable to perform this functionality. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no any ready made library for this. You need to calculate and store the button position(x,y) and use `TranslateAnimation` for move animation and LayoutParams setMargins to  set button position from one position to another position, same operation will be done with otherviews.

**TranslateAnimation** For Animation

```
final Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,100,0,0);
// set Animation for 5 sec
animation.setDuration(5000);
//for button stops in the new position.
animation.setFillAfter(true);
im.startAnimation(animation);
```

**Move Button** To move button set margin

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);            
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); 
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```